# Django CSRFToken middleware appends to URL and shows up after making a “PUT” request to the server. (AJAX issue)

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I’m working on a *Django Python/Javascript* project. The PUT request is done through the client and sent back to the server. After sending the request successfully, the page makes a refresh which is causing the exposure of the csrf token middleware in the URL. I already implemented **AJAX**, **returning false**, added an **event.preventDefault()**, passed a **cookie** through the header of the fetch, used **async functions**, and added a **try and catch** syntax. And I can’t figure out why it is not affecting the resubmission. I need to stop the webpage from refreshing once the submission is done so that the *csrf_token* won't show appended to the URL.

Hopefully, someone can let me know what I’m not seeing here. Thanks!

```
// Set global variables to use in form submission
var id, upt_prodName, upt_prodPrice, upt_prodDescpt;

// Block to populate textarea that allows the user to update product info.
 
 const editProd_view = (response) => {
 
  let prod_id = response.id;
  let edit_name = response.name;
  let edit_price = response.price;
  let edit_descpt = response.description;
 
 
 let prod_idUpt = (document.querySelector("#prod_idUpt").innerHTML = prod_id);
 let new_name = (document.querySelector(
  "#editProdName"
   ).innerHTML = edit_name);
 let new_price = (document.querySelector(
  "#editProdPrice"
   ).innerHTML = edit_price);
 let new_textarea = (document.querySelector(
  "#editProdDescpt"
   ).innerHTML = edit_descpt);
 
 id = prod_id;
 
//On submit, send product info to update the product.

 const edit_prod = (document.querySelector(
  "#editProd_form").onsubmit = async () => {
     try {

// Get all values from textarea to update content.
     upt_prodName = document.getElementById("editProdName").value;
     new_prodPrice = document.getElementById("editProdPrice").value;
     new_prodDescpt = document.getElementById("editProdDescpt").value;
 
     const res = await fetch(
       `/editProduct/${id}`,
          {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: upt_prodName,
      description: upt_prodDescpt,
      price: upt_prodPrice,
     }),
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
console.log("result ->", result);
    });
} catch (err) {
  console.error("err", err);
}

//Once the post has been submitted, return false to prevent reloading.

 edit_prod.handleForm();
 return false;
 });

return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah inside django for post and put, delete requires a csrf token, my solution

you can do this

```
<form>
 <button id="onsubmit" method="{{csrf_token}}">submit</button>
</form>

$(document).on(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '#onsubmit', function() {
      var token = $(this).attr("method")
      const res = await fetch(
       `/editProduct/${id}`,
          {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRFToken": token,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: upt_prodName,
      description: upt_prodDescpt,
      price: upt_prodPrice,
     }),
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
console.log("result ->", result);
    });
} catch (err) {
  console.error("err", err);
}
   })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried implementing your solution but it is not quite what I need. When the "PUT" request is sent it does making the update in the server but during the process, the webpage refreshes to get the item list and displays it along with the change made. In this instance is when the csrf_token gets exposed. Thus, I'm thinking the problem might be in the "GET" request for the list of items on that webpage. That's why I'm trying to prevent the webpage from refreshing once the submission is done.